# Using GDI+ to draw tooltip

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+, tooltip

I'm new to GDI+ programming and am looking for some advice.

I am loading an image from a file and displaying it using the following functions (some pseudo code included):

```
Gdiplus::Image *i = new Gdiplus::Image(file, other parameters ... );
Gdiplus::DrawImage(i, other parameters ... );
```

I would like to associate a tooltip with the image. Is there any way that I can automatically set/attach a tooltip to the Gdiplus::Image objact (or any other Gdiplus control that I wish to draw for that matter)?

If not, how can such functionality be achieved? I have looked at CToolTipCtrl in WTL but don't know how to attach it to the Gdiplus::Image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this more, I've realised that this is not possible, so to speak. You must use GDI+ to draw your own tool tip my monitoring mouse events to see when it is hovering over something, then using the device context to do the drawing withing the mouse hover event handler.