# Using GDI+ with legacy C based win32 system using GDI

Tags: c, performance, winapi, gdi+, gdi

Working on a system written using win32 C/C++, it uses GDI to draw cross section of a complex machine (heat exchanger), most of the code written is C based (not C++ and hence no Object Oriented Programing). I am wondering whether I could use GDI+ with this system.

Currently all of the code is using basic GDI primitives like HPEN, HBRUSH, Polygon(), Rectangle(), MoveToEx(), LineTo(), DrawText() etc. One good reason to enable or start using GDI+ is to draw context details for a component inform of tooltip, please see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145898/using-gdi-to-draw-tooltip). I have read that font rendering of GDI+ is not that efficient as GDI is ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance/)).

Summarizing, can I use GDI+ with this aged system (re-write is not possible as it has a huge code base). Secondly, would I get performance hit if I move to GDI+?

Comment: You can draw with whatever system you want, at worst you can even start to draw with GDI on a bitmap, then go on with GDI+, and in the end blit the bitmap on screen or wherever GDI initially drew; the switch from drawing onscreen to drawing on a bitmap for the legacy part of code should just be in the DC creation. For the performance hit, there's no better way than to measure it directly.

Comment: It is not impossible to use the underlying C-based api, but it certainly cruel and unusual punishment and poorly documented.  Time to add some C++ code to this project, declare your C++ painting helper functions `extern "C"` so the linker will be happy.

Answer (score -2):

> I am wondering whether I could use GDI+ with this system.

The [GDI+ documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798.aspx) suggests the answer is yes.

In particular it says:

> **Developer audience**
>
> The GDI+ C++ class-based interface is designed for use by C/C++ programmers. Familiarity with the Windows graphical user interface and message-driven architecture is required.

As to question if it will be slower, I suspect you will see very little if any loss in performance, only because this will be nothing more than a thin C++ layer over those same Win32 GDI API functions.

Comment: No, GDI+ is not a thin layer on top of GDI. GDI+ is its own custom drawing model that does everything from scratch in order to provide higher quality graphics (and IIRC GDI+ does it all in software, which is why it has a performance hit over GDI, but I'm not 100% sure). That being said, the OP specifically asked for a C interface, and GDI+ does have one: the "flat API" (but here be dragons). As for the OP, since you do not need to please as many people as possible and know your requirements, evaluate and benchmark to decide which API meets your goals the best.

Comment: The link I posted says *designed for use by C/C++ programmers* and that suggests to me it is also a viable solution for C programmers.

Comment: Correct, but then you talked about the C++ interface in the rest of your answer, or at least that's how I read it. I was just providing the C-specific information to highlight it more directly, in case the OP reached the same implication by accident. Apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: See [GDI+ Flat API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533969.aspx).

Comment: I'm afraid, andlabs is correct. GDI+ does most of its rendering in software (like all of the anti-aliased line drawing), and takes a **significant** performance hit over using GDI. Also, you don't seem to address the question, at what granularity GDI and GDI+ code can be mixed. In all, it merely states the obvious: GDI+ (like **all** other Windows APIs) can be used from C.

Comment: @IInspectable GDI and GDI+ can be mixed, but only in so far that a GDI+ drawing surface can be created on top of an `HDC` so that GDI+ graphics can be rendered to GDI. But you can't use GDI to draw GDI+ graphics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know, and it's a relevant detail, that's completely missing from this proposed answer.